# How to sort a 2D numpy object array based on a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy object array:

```
aa = np.array([["aaa","05","1","a"],
               ["ccc","30","2","v"],
               ["ddd","50","2","v"],
               ["bbb","10","1","v"]])
```

and the following list:

```
sample_ids = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

I would like to sort the numpy array based on the list so that I get the following:

```
[["aaa","05","1","a"],
 ["bbb","10","1","v"],
 ["ccc","30","2","v"],
 ["ddd","50","2","v"]]
```

**Edit**:

If there are keys (in sample_ids) that are not present in the array. The resulting array would not include these missing keys (i.e. no addition of empty rows).
So if we have the following:

```
sample_ids = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]
```

The final array would still be the same.

Also, if the array would contain a row (i.e. row key) that is missing from the keys. That row would be left out of the resulting array as well.

**Edit 2:**
Starting from Nick's answer, I came up with this to deal with absent keys.

```
sample_ids2 = ["aaa", "bbb", "eee", "ccc", "ddd"]

idxs = []
for i,v in enumerate(sample_ids2):
    if str(list(aa.T[0])).find(v) != -1:
        k = list(aa.T[0]).index(v)
        idxs.append(k)
    else:
        print(v + " was not found!!!")

print(aa[idxs])
```

Output:

```
[['aaa' '05' '1' 'a']
 ['bbb' '10' '1' 'v']
 ['ccc' '30' '2' 'v']
 ['ddd' '50' '2' 'v']]
```

Comment: I have two questions: first, your data is a string table, do you want to solve it with numpy rather than pandas which is better at handling such data? Second, do we need to consider duplicate/missing keys? (ie. `sample_ids = ["aaa", "aaa", "ddd"]` )

Comment: Thanks very much for the input everyone. I would stick with numpy for now. And yes actually, it is possible that keys (sample_ids) would be absent in the array. In that case, these keys would need to be left out of the resulting sorted array. More details in edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of possible solutions. Using numpy:

```
subs = list(aa.T[0])
idxs = [subs.index(i) for i in sample_ids if i in subs]
res = aa[idxs]
# array([['aaa', '05', '1', 'a'],
#        ['bbb', '10', '1', 'v'],
#        ['ccc', '30', '2', 'v'],
#        ['ddd', '50', '2', 'v']], dtype='<U3')
```

Using pandas:

```
res = np.array(pd.DataFrame(aa).set_index(0).reindex(sample_ids).dropna().reset_index())
# array([['aaa', '05', '1', 'a'],
#        ['bbb', '10', '1', 'v'],
#        ['ccc', '30', '2', 'v'],
#        ['ddd', '50', '2', 'v']], dtype=object)
```

For both cases, if `sample_ids = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]`, the output will be the same.

If `sample_ids = ["ddd", "aaa", "bbb"]`, the output will be:

```
array([['ddd', '50', '2', 'v'],
       ['aaa', '05', '1', 'a'],
       ['bbb', '10', '1', 'v']])
```

Comment: @julio514 I've updated my solutions to work when there are values in either `aa` or `sample_ids` which are not in the other.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Nick's first approach:

```
# first build a dictionary of value: position
key = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(sample_ids)}
# {'aaa': 0, 'bbb': 1, 'ccc': 2, 'ddd': 3}

# then sort based on this key
out = aa[np.argsort(np.vectorize(key.get)(aa[:, 0]))]
```

If you want to be able to handle missing values (with `-1` as default key to sort it first, if you prefer last use `np.inf`):

```
out = aa[np.argsort(np.vectorize(lambda x: key.get(x, -1))(aa[:, 0]))]
```

Output:

```
array([['aaa', '05', '1', 'a'],
       ['bbb', '10', '1', 'v'],
       ['ccc', '30', '2', 'v'],
       ['ddd', '50', '2', 'v']], dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, using [`numpy.broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
aa[np.argmax(aa[:,0] == np.array(sample_ids)[:, None], axis=1), :]
```

Another possible solution, using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
np.vstack([aa[aa[:,0] == x, :] for x in sample_ids])
```

Output:

```
array([['aaa', '05', '1', 'a'],
       ['bbb', '10', '1', 'v'],
       ['ccc', '30', '2', 'v'],
       ['ddd', '50', '2', 'v']], dtype='<U3')
```